# Highscore & Game Stats in 2nd View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, nsuserdefaults

I'm looking on building on my current release of my game 'Ginger Cat'. Now i've got the gameplay to the desired level I would like to add a game stats page that will compliment the Game Centre achievements and leaderboards.

At present my `GameScene.swift` holds my highscore and displays on the correct view controller using this code

```
    highScore = 0
    highScoreLabelNode.fontName = "Helvetica-Bold"
    highScoreLabelNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2.48, y: self.frame.size.height / 1.17 )
    highScoreLabelNode.fontSize = 30
    highScoreLabelNode.alpha = 0.7
    highScoreLabelNode.text = "Highscore \(score)"

    let highScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if (highScoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") != nil){
        highScore = highScoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") as! NSInteger!
        highScoreLabelNode.text = NSString(format: "Highscore : %i", highScore) as String
    }
    self.addChild(highScoreLabelNode)
```

Now what I would like to do is display the same highscore on the `statsViewController` currently connected and set up.  Obviously I want to use `NSUserDefaults` but it doesn't work just replicating the above code in the stats view controller.

UPDATE TO INCLUDE CODE FROM `StatsViewController`

```
let highscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
highscoreDefault.setValue(highScore, forKey: "Highscore") //Expected Declaration error on this line
highscoreDefault.synchronize()

highScoreLabelNode.fontName = "Helvetica-Bold"
highScoreLabelNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2.48, y: self.frame.size.height / 1.17 )
highScoreLabelNode.fontSize = 30
highScoreLabelNode.alpha = 0.7
highScoreLabelNode.text = "Highscore \(score)"

self.addChild(highScoreLabelNode)
```

Would anyone be able to help here? Once I do the highscore I can work out the rest of the achievements myself.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Did you synchronize your NSUserDefaults after updating or creating an entry in it?

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

Comment: @RaymondBrion My highscore is working correctly in the `GameScene`, I'm just having problems displaying it in a separate view controller, I've edited the above to reflect.  Also I am synchronising my highscore if it's greater then the score by using this line in the update func `highscoreDefault.synchronize()`

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you wanted this on stats...

```
let highscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let score = highscoreDefault.valueForKey("HighScore")

highScoreLabelNode.fontName = "Helvetica-Bold"
highScoreLabelNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2.48, y: self.frame.size.height / 1.17 )
highScoreLabelNode.fontSize = 30
highScoreLabelNode.alpha = 0.7
highScoreLabelNode.text = "Highscore \(score)"


self.addChild(highScoreLabelNode)
```

You aren't trying to set the high score you are trying to get it. Hopefully that helps.